# my read functions reads data out of my file

Tags: c

so I'm working on a project where I have to read BUFFER_SIZE bytes (which will be defined as a macro during the compilation) from a file on each call, and the allowed functions are {read(),malloc()} and when I use my code in the case below it reads the file plus some data I don't know where it came from, BUFFER_SIZE = 10 in this case

file contains :

```
    01234567890123456789012345678901234567890
    1
```

code :

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
         int fd;
         char *buff;
         int r;
         buff=(char *) malloc((BUFFER_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(char));
         fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
         r = 1;
         while (r)
        {
             printf("BEFORE : %d\n",r);
             r = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
             printf("AFTER : %d\n",r);
             buff[r] = '\0';
             printf("%s\n",buff);
        }
   }
```

Comment: you did not set the buffer values to 0, so how do you know buff[BUFFER_SIZE] will contains a null terminator character ('\0')  It could have random garbage in it also.

Comment: `%s` requires the argument to be a null-terminated string. `read()` doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: You could use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`. It initializes the buffer to all zeroes.

Comment: Can you `#define read fread`? Seems like it is better.

Comment: What *does* the program output? I see you have terminated the string with `buff[r] = '\0';` and allowed the extra storage too.

Comment: Also, what do you expect it to output and why? In any case, error handling is missing, just read the documentation for `read()`.

Comment: @Neil: How would that macro be useful? Those two functions have a different number of parameters.

Comment: It seems like the task would be better suited to `fread` instead of the lower-level non-ISO `read`, (it probably doesn't matter in OP's case because that's what the assignment is.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.